# STS - Spring Boot Application - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have imported a project from a GIT repository and when trying to launch on Tomcat 8 I receive the following error:

The requested resource is not available.

The url launched is http://localhost:8080/[project_name]/

I have tried appending the various html files (i.e. home.html) to the url to no avail.  Can someone please help me diagnose the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: please share the git repo. the link

Answer (score 3):

Without any additional configuration, Spring Boot apps will launch at `http://localhost:8080`.

If you want to add a context path, add the following property to your application.properties file:

`server.context-path=my-project-name`

Then it will launch at `localhost:8080/my-project-name`.